# MySql query between range values(single record)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database

I have below data in my database table

```
id       time      time_slots
1        time1     09:00-10:30,12:15-14:00,16:30-19:30
2        time2     14:00-15:15,18:30-19:30
3        time3     08:30-10:00,13:00-15:00,15:30-18:00
4        time4     13:00-15:00
5        time5     15:00-16:00,17:30-18:30
```

Now, if the current time is 13:30 then I want 3 records(id 1,3,4) from the above table. The final result will be:

```
id
1
3
4
```

Please help me to find out the solution in the best way. Your help will be very helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which data type is the column time_slots ?????

Comment: For now, time_slots will be comma separated string.

Comment: you should change the struc as  suggested  in the answer  below

Answer (score 6):

I think you can optimize your table structure, else it will take a lot of time to get data when the number of records in the table is large.

try implementing the below structure it will be easy.

**Time_table**

```
id       time      
1        time1    
2        time2     
3        time3     
4        time4     
5        time5
```

**Time_slot_table**

```
id   time_table_id(fk)  start_time  end_time
1    1                   09::00      10:30
2    1                   12:15       14:00
3    1                   16:30       19:30
4    2                   14:15       15:15
5    2                   18:30       19:30
```

Now run below query to get data that comes in range

```
SELECT time 
FROM Time_table 
JOIN Time_slot_table ON Time_slot_table.time_table_id = Time_table.id 
WHERE current_time BETWEEN Time_slot_table.start_time AND Time_slot_table.end_time
```

Comment: @KushalNanavati I haven't verified query let me know if you face any issue in query

Comment: Yeah, I have verified and it's working. But I am working on if the case in which I have given in my question (single table with multiple range values). If you find the solution for that then it will be appreciated.